# How can I extract test results from Flash?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I've got a suite of unit tests for my project (pure AS3), and they all work brilliantly outputting standard JUnit XML to the trace output window. However, when I tried to get my test suite running on our continuous integration server I ran up against a wall.

Flash is a sandboxed beast, isolated from the file system. I can't see an intuitive way to get this generated JUnit XML in to our CI software so it can be verified as passing.

I've taken a shot at implementing the approach shown in [Continuous Integration with Flex](http://www.eyefodder.com/blog/2006/05/continuous_integration_with_fl_1.shtml),
 but it relies on reading trace output logged to flashlog.txt that is prone to failure on many fronts (debug player must be installed, flashlog.txt must be created, mm.cfg file must be configured properly). Also, I find that some of the time it fails to find the results in the flashlog and the build fails despite all the tests passing. This could be because I have too many tests and some are being pushed out of the log file.

Surely there is an easier way that I'm just not seeing. Has anyone accomplished reliable continuous integration with automated testing in AS3?

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash sandboxing sure can be a major pain in the butt. Have you looked into run your tests as an AIR application? This gets rid of all the sand box issues and offers a ton of great API's for accessing the local file system without user interaction. It should be far easier to integrate into your CI system.

Comment: I have considered AIR, but since my project is pure AS3 I'm wary of building my tests against another SDK in the same project. I'm also not sure if FDT/Flash Builder would play nice with both the AIR SDK and the Flex 4.1 SDK in the same project. I imagine I could create a separate AIR project and then link my project's code in to it and build the tests from there, but now the tests and project code are in two projects (making the project a pain to get up and running from scratch).

Answer (score 1):

Install xampp, have the flash test suite send the data to the localhost server from xampp then have xampp write it to a file.
Assuming your application has access to the local file system

Answer (score 0):

Even if you've never used php before, it would be pretty simple for you to write a little script that takes in data and dumps it out to a file. Then in Flash you can send that script your XML data. That is, make a POST to that script with the XML tagging along as a URLVariable.